# How to access lists inside a tuple inside a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a newbie to python. Trying to learn how to access Lists inside a Tuple inside a List. My List is:

```
holidays = [(0,),
 (1, [2, 16]),
 (2, [20]),
 (4, [14]),
 (5, [29]),
 (7, [4]),
 (9, [4]),
 (11, [23, 24]),
 (12, [25])]
```

I would like to know the best way to access each tuple and its list in a more efficient way. I tried using:

```
for i, tuples in enumerate(holidays):
    for list in tuples:
        print list
```

But i get the following error:

```
for list in tuples:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your first element is `0` not a tuple, an `int` and not iterable

Comment: first element is a tuple. it got editted by someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the i in the first for loop:

```
for tuples in enumerate(holidays):
    for list in tuples:
        print list
```

Comment: ahh.. thank you! now trying to get to each tuple and list specifically. Would you be able to put your insight on it?

Comment: What do  you mean exactly provide an example

Answer (score 1):

short version

`[y for x in holidays if isinstance(x, tuple) for y in x if isinstance(y, list)]`

You can't do a for .. in  LOOP on an integer, that's why the program cras

Comment: Thank you. Will appreciate if you can explain what really is happening in this

Comment: I use list comprehension to make a list. You can try [x*x for x in range(10)] to have all x squares from 0 to 9.
Then on the first loop i take all elements that are instances of a tuple in holidays : `for x in holidays if isinstance(x, tuple)`
Then for each x element found, i get the elements that are instances of a list. :  `for y in x if isinstance(y, list)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your first element 0 to (0), Also, remove 'i' from your for loop, as told by Stavros, it will work.

```
holidays = [([0]),
 (1, [2, 16]),
 (2, [20]),
 (4, [14]),
 (5, [29]),
 (7, [4]),
 (9, [4]),
 (11, [23, 24]),
 (12, [25])]
```

tuples in enumerate(holidays):
    list in tuples:
        print list

Comment: You have seenmy answer ,and you propose the same thing just hit the +1 arrow, don't post duplicate answer

Comment: Had to mention the change in the dataset. Also, I can't vote yet, otherwise I would have.

Comment: Basicly you can vote but it's is not seed until you have a reputation

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your *holidays*  list is not uniform: the first entry is an integer (0), the others are tuples.

```
holidays = [0,  # <- integer
    (1, [2, 16]),
    (2, [20]),
    (4, [14]),
    (5, [29]),
    (7, [4]),
    (9, [4]),
    (11, [23, 24]),
    (12, [25])]
```

Here is a possible loop:

```
for entry in holidays:
    if entry == 0:
        continue  # don't know what to do with zero
    month, days = entry
    print(month, days)
```

We use unpaking to extract the *month* and the *days*.
See [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in the Python tutorial.

Comment: I have made initial 0 as a (0,) tuple as well. Ran your suggested code and it gives the following error:     month, days = entry
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack